# 2 different auth types on .Net API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a .net 5 API that runs as the backbone of our service.

Currently we have b2c set up within the API and our angular app to auth users.

But now we have a secondary daemon that needs to authorise onto the api to be able to do its thing.

What would be best practise to achieve this? Since we need to use client credentials and not user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

•   You can use the **Azure Maps** resource in Azure to ensure that a daemon app securely authenticates the API and authorizes it to do the thing. Azure Maps supports two authentication methods, viz., **Azure Active Directory Authentication** and **Shared Key authentication**. AAD method maps the **‘Client ID’**, i.e., the service principal or the account used for REST API request to the application/API through it and the other method, i.e., **shared key authentication** uses primary and secondary key as the subscription key for it as it relies on passing the key generated by the Azure Maps account to each request in Azure Maps.

•   For more information, you can surely refer to the documentation below on the detailed steps to follow for the efficient and correct use of the above stated methods for a secondary daemon app to authorize onto an API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-secure-daemon-app

In the above link, **shared key authentication with Azure key vault** and **Azure AD role based access control** are discussed.

Comment: Where do you get the need for Azure Maps from? I don't see anything in the question that makes Azure Maps relevant

Comment: @AlexAIT, Azure Maps is a convenience best practice recommended approach for the type of scenario that you are demanding. For that purpose, I would suggest you to please have a look into it.